Changing Math font for website made with `pkgdown`
I am using bslib in pkgdown to customize a package website. While I am able to change the base font and the code font, I am unable to change the font used to render math equations supplied via LaTeX. What is the standard way to set math font when using bslib.
I tried looking up both the pkgdown and bslib documentation, but no yml attribute was mentioned that controls the MathJAX font.
Here is the _pkgdown.yml file:
url: ~
template:
  bootstrap: 5
  bslib:
    base_font: {google: "Roboto"}
    heading_font: {google: "Roboto Slab"}
    code_font: {google: "Fira Code"}

This changes the main text font to Roboto and the code font to Fira Code but it does not change the math font. How do I change the math font? Is there a YAML key value pair (something like `math_font: {}) that controls the MathJax font?
